Elementary consequence of non-abelian class field theory
Bogdan Grechuk recently asked for elementary consequences of the Langlands program. His question reminded me of something that has nagged at me for a while. Before I state my question, let me give a bit of background and motivation.
My favorite way of motivating quadratic reciprocity is to show someone the prime factorizations of $n^2 - 5$ for $n=3,4,5,\ldots$ and to ask why we never see a prime ending in $3$ or $7$. The explanation, of course, is that if $p$ is an odd prime and $p \mid (n^2-5)$ then
$$1 = \biggl({5 \over p}\biggr) = \biggl({p \over 5}\biggr)$$
by quadratic reciprocity. I think it is not too hard to jazz up this example to give an elementary motivation for (abelian) class field theory, since in the abelian case, the splitting behavior of primes is controlled by congruence conditions, and congruence conditions are pretty easy to grasp.
My question is, can we come up with a similar elementary motivation for nonabelian class field theory? In his essay, Representation theory: Its rise and role in number theory, Langlands writes down the polynomial $x^5 + 10x^3 -10x^2+35x-18$ and then remarks:

It is irreducible modulo $p$ for $p = 7, 13, 19, 29, 43, 47, 59, \ldots$ and factors into linear factors modulo $p$ for $p = 2063, 2213, 2953, 3631, \ldots\,$. These lists can be continued indefinitely, but it is doubtful that even the most perspicacious and experienced mathematician would detect any regularity. It is none the less there.

Though Langlands does go on to explain some of the theory behind this example, the reader who is hoping for an elementary example of the "regularity" alluded to above will be disappointed, because nothing like that is described explicitly in the paper.
Of course, nothing like congruence conditions exist in the nonabelian case. To describe the "regularity" properly, we need to introduce modular forms, which are difficult to describe in a completely elementary manner. But I'm reluctant to give up so quickly. Modular forms enjoy symmetries that should (I think) be translatable into identities between certain infinite series. Can we, for example, take the infinite sequence $p = 2063, 2213, 2953, 3631, \ldots$ above and write down some kind of striking infinite series identity or identities that they obey? I realize I'm being a bit vague here, but my question is in the same spirit as Bogdan Grechuk's question. That is, I'd like some sort of maximally elementary statement that can give the novice some flavor of the remarkable structure that the Langlands program aims to elucidate.

EDIT: Denis T's comment points to Emerton's answer to another MO question which is very close to what I am looking for. If I understand it correctly, it says that if we define integers $a_n$ by the equation
$$q \prod_{r=1}^\infty (1-q^r)(1-q^{23r}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n q^n,$$
then the polynomial $x^6 - 6x^4 + 9x^2 + 23$ splits completely into distinct linear factors mod $p$ if and only if $a_p = 2$.
One shortcoming of this example is that it is arguably still within the realm of abelian class field theory, in particular of the theory of Hilbert class fields. It turns out that the polynomial $x^6 - 6x^4 + 9x^2 + 23$ splits completely into distinct linear factors mod $p$ if and only if $p$ is an odd prime of the form $x^2 + 23y^2$ and $p\ne 23$ (see for example Theorem 5.26 of Cox's book Primes of the Form $x^2 + ny^2$). Nevertheless, it would definitely answer my question if someone could write down an analogous explicit statement (for some other polynomial) that is still conjectural. Failing that, an analogous statement for a more interesting Galois group than $\mathfrak{S}_3$ would also be a good answer.

https://mathoverflow.net/a/12382/ Does this answer provide the kind of "striking identity" you want?

@DenisT Ah, that's very close! Maybe you can post a brief summary of Emerton's answer there as an answer here. If nobody comes up with something better, I can accept it.

The scope of the question is quite lost on me. What do you mean here with "non-abelian class field theory"? If you just mean Langlands program, how exactly is this different from Bogdan's question you have asked?

Possibly one can take the modular form in Emerton's example and get a suitable congruence with a higher weight modular form, which one could describe in terms of Eisenstein series/theta functions.  Would this be what you want?

@Wojowu I'm trying to narrow the focus to an elementary statement about the set of primes with respect to which a polynomial with non-abelian Galois group will (for example) split completely.

@Kimball Maybe, although I think you'd have to flesh it out a bit before I could tell.

Well, elementary is subjective, but one prediction of non-abelian class field theory is Dedekind's conjecture that the Riemann zeta function divides all Dedekind zeta functions. In particular, every zero of $\zeta(s)$ is also a zero of $\zeta_K(s)$. Surprisingly, abelian class field theory is sufficient to verify this for all Galois number fields, but the non-Galois case seems to require non-abelian class field theory which is still in the making.

This is known as Dedekind's conjecture, and more generally one believes that $\zeta_L(s)/\zeta_K(s)$ is holomorphic for any number field extension $L/K$. As this quotient factors as a product of Artin L-functions, this follows from Artin's conjecture on their holomorphy, which follows from Langlands reciprocity by identifying them with automorphic L-functions.

@Wojowu Yes. The words "Dedekind's conjecture" also appear in my post. I restricted to a special case and omitted the representation theoretic details for simplicity of exposition.

Ah somehow I've missed that you calling it by name, I promise I have actually read your post :P The goal of my comment was mostly to indicate how these results follow from "non-abelian class field theory", hopefully complementing your post.

Turns out I have a recent book that does this; Hiramatsu and Saito (2017)  An Introduction to Non-Abelian Class Field Theory   ::subtitle:: Automorphic Forms of Weight $1$  and $2$-Dimensional Galois Representations
Chapter 5  is $2$-Dimensional Galois Representations of odd type and non-dihedral cusp forms of weight $1$   pages 93-106.
Chapter 5, section 3  is The Case of type $A_5$  pages 101-103
Chapter 5, section 3.1 is  The First Example due to Buhler  pages 101 and 102.
He considers $F(x) = x^5 + 10 x^3 - 10 x^2 + 35 x - 18 .$  Then $K$  is the splitting field over $\mathbb Q$   and $G$ is the Galois group.
Theorem 5.9 (Buhler)  There is an icosahedral representation
$$  \rho : Gal(\bar{\mathbb Q} / \mathbb Q) \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb C) $$
of conductor 800  such that $L(s, \rho)$ is an entire function of $s.$
They outline Buhler's proof.


The other references in this subsection : G. Frey (1994),  Construction and arithmetical applications of modular forms of low weight   Deligne and Serre (1974)  Formes modulaires de poids $1$  they say pages 507-530


Preview:
https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_To_Non_abelian_Class_Field/_E0tDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover

Did your post get cut off, or is it meant to end with "they say pages 507–530"?

@LSpice  I guess cut off, in that I went to look for more bibliographic material and saved the draft. Anyway, I think I have exactly the right reference for this question. Oh, I was going to check whether Deligne and Serre is in a book or a journal,  it says Ann. scient. Ec. Norm. Sup., series, t.7 (1974), 507-530. I'm thinking journal....  https://annales-ens.centre-mersenne.org/index.php/ASENS

Re, I find that French publications sometimes tend to blur the line between journal and book, so I dare not speculate.  Here's a free Numdam link.

@WillJagy Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this yields a statement that I would consider elementary.

Also in response to a comment you repeated a couple of times, the fact that Buhler's proof was an entire Ph.D. thesis doesn't mean that an elementary statement can't be extracted, especially since I'm not asking for a complete description of what's going on, but just a striking corollary that can be understood with minimal background.

@TimothyChow  well, I don't think there is anything available as pleasant as  Theorem 1, Table 1,  in http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

@WillJagy I only skimmed that paper, but it belongs to the realm of classical (abelian) class field theory, doesn't it? As I hinted in my question, it's true that we can't expect anything as pleasant in the non-abelian case, but that doesn't mean nothing elementary can be said.

@TimothyChow  The table of contents for Buhler is on line, the example is discussed in a chapter, pages 80-94, and may or may not give a  clear  simple description of primes for which the quintic splits. So I would check MathSciNet for citations to Buhler. There is some mild sort of regularity from Chebotarev, it splits for 1/60 of the primes.

@WillJagy I did actually correspond with Joe Buhler before posting here on MathOverflow. A complete description of the primes for which the quintic splits is going to have to use the language of modular forms, which is not quite elementary enough for what I'm angling for (unless there's a Borcherds product, which I suspect there isn't in this case). But again, that doesn't mean we can't extract an elementary corollary. I doubt that searching the literature will help because this is really a pedagogical question rather than something a research paper would address.

@TimothyChow  I suggest you add the correspondence with Buhler to the question; the fact of it,  his book title, how it seems that Langlands picked his book example (apparently there is another in that chapter).  For my first question in 2010, I felt there was too much to fit in the question, so I put relevant things on a web page; the point being that Kevin Buzzard looked at those and answered... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12486/integers-not-represented-by-2-x2-x-y-3-y2-z3-z     and   then http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.cgi

@WillJagy I'm not sure that it adds much to say that Buhler didn't have an answer to my question.
